\$I_{on}\$ and \$I_{off}\$ of MOSFET
I have a question from a test (translation from my language to English). We want to produce a MOSFET with \$\frac{I_\text{on}}{I_\text{off}}=10^4\$: we also know that \$s=80\text{mV/decade}\$, so what is the minimum threshold voltage?
I have the answer from a friend, but I cannot understand what he did ( the final answer is true, its the same as the professor ):
$$
\frac{I_\text{on}}{I_\text{off}}=\frac{100\bullet W/L}{100W/L\bullet 10^{-V_T/S}}10^4
$$ and from here we deduce \$V_T=0.32V\$
My question is, what is in that formula the value of \$I_\text{on}\$?
I know the value of \$I_\text{off}\$ , but I don't know exactly the vale of the former parameter. It seems like he assumes \$V_G=V_T\$, and if so, what is the reason?

I'm not clear on how ION and IOFF are defined in this question. One sensible definition of ION is ION: VDS=VGS=VDD and IOFF: VGS=0 and VDS=VDD. (In some applications a different definition might make sense.) I don't see a unique answer without specifying VDD.

Ahh, we was not given anything else.
I guess I will just stick to the idea that according to the answers its true and see at future exercise if it is denying it or its ok
Thanks anyway!!

It doesn't matter what the value of either on or off current is. You are given their ratio, and you only work with the ratio. The formula uses the ratio as well.
